# Source-code formatting: statements on one line

Tags: formatting, visual-studio-2008, source-code

Is there a way, or tool, or add-in, to automatically format code so that each statement is on a single line and not word-wrapped across multiple lines? For example:

Before:

```
// Store our custom animation data in the Tag property of the model.
model.Tag = new SkinningData(animationClips, 
                             bindPose,
                             inverseBindPose);
```

After:

```
// Store our custom animation data in the Tag property of the model.
model.Tag = new SkinningData(animationClips, bindPose, inverseBindPose);
```

In other words, I'd like to take some code that is formatted like the Before example and get it to the After format.

Answer (score 1):

With [uncrustify](http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) you can do a lot, unfortunately it has to be ran outside of the IDE (no integration)